# ElasticSearch PHP syntax

Tags: php, elasticsearch, yii2

I'm new to ElasticSearch and don't really understand how the queries works...
My indexing example

```
 {
  "_index" : "indexing001",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "3",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 242,
  "_primary_term" : 2,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "type" : 1,
    "sub_type" : null,
    "user" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "tk6z2 gcnouvqmr"
    },
    "editor_user" : [ ],
    "content" : [
      {
        "title" : "Title #3",
        "short_text" : "Article #3 short text",
        "full_text" : "Article #3 full text",
        "locale" : "de-DE"
      }
    ],
    "flags" : [ ],
    "location" : [ ],
    "start_date" : 1658793600,
    "end_date" : 1658793600,
    "_users" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I want to query the text to match the field `content.title` and `content.short_text`, query user by `_users` field.
For example my function is:

```
public static function search(
        string $text = '',
        int $user = 0
    ): array
    {
        try {
            $model = new someModelClass();
            $fields = [
                'content.title',
                'content.short_text',
            ];
            $result = $model::find()->query( [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query'  => $text,
                            'fields' => $fields,
                        ],
                    ],
                    'filter' => [
                        [ 'term' => [ '_users.id' => $user ] ],
                        [ 'term' => [ '_users' => [] ] ],
                    ]
                ],
            ] )->all();

            return $result;
        }
        catch ( Exception $e ) {
            throw new Exception( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
```

convert it to SQL it should be something like: `SELECT * FROM 'indexing001' WHERE (content.title LIKE %search% OR content.short_text LIKE %search%) AND (users.id = 1 OR users = '')`
How to write it in ElasticSearch query?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `(users.id = 1 OR users = '')` doesn't make sense

Comment: `filter` is using for exact match - yes or no

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case i would recommend to use the [Elasticsearch-PHP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html) client.

Please [install](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/installation.html) appropriate client using composer.

For a match query like below

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "testField" : "abc"
        }
    }
}'
```

You can make a query in your PHP Script like this

```php
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'testField' => 'abc'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$results = $client->search($params);
```

Check more operations [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/operations.html).

Comment: yes I know it. But the question is how to convert from SQL to ES query?

Comment: Thats a very broader question. For this you need to refer [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html). You need to check which what type of query you hitting in SQL and convert it into ES query. If you want to direct hit SQL query to ES I would recommend to check SQL interface https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to reproduce your SQL and provide JSON query example, u will ez adapt it to PHP query method.

```js
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "should": [
       {"multi_match": {
           "fields": ["content.title", "content.short_text"],
           "query": "%query here%"
       }}
     ],
     "filter": {
       "bool": {
        "should": [
           {"match": {"user.id": "%id here%"}},
           {"match": {"user": []}},
        ]
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```